# Why does total angular momentum and parity of the ground state of $^{203}\rm Tl$ come out as $1/2^+$ rather than $11/2^-$

Tags: angular-momentum, nuclear-physics

In the book 'Introductory Nuclear Physics' By Krane, chapter 5, Question 3, It asks for a reason why we don't see a $11/2^-$ ground state in $^{201}Tl$ and instead measure a $1/2^+$ State (where $11/2^-$ and $1/2^+$ represent the total angular momentum and parity ($J^\pi$)).It mentions that this is also the case with $^{207}Pb$ and $^{199}Hg$ where $13/2^+$ is predicted but $1/2^-$ is measured.

The question hints that this is caused by the pairing force being stronger with larger orbital angular momentum (L)

Filling in the shells for Thallium (81 protons) I can see the theoretically expected $11/2^-$ state as the unpaired proton resides in the $1h_{11/2}$ shell. From here the only way I can see it being possible to obtain a $1/2^+$ state is for a proton to move from the $3s_{1/2}$ shell below the $1h_{11/2}$ into the $1h_{11/2}$ and pair with the proton already in that shell. This would leave an unpaired proton in $3s_{1/2}$ and give the measured $1/2^+$

As far as I can tell there are no answers both online or in the book and so I am a little unsure about this question. If this is the correct way to go about it then is there any way that you would be able to work this out theoretically without knowing before that you should get a $1/2^+$ state?

Comment: Hello! You can write sub/superscripts using MathJax (LaTeX) typesetting. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/).

Comment: Thank you. I have changed it to Thallium and improved the formatting